# Insert Checkbox value to Database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, forms, checkbox

so im trying to store values from a checkbox into my database
It works if I use a normal Textbox but as soon as I attempt it with a checkbox it doesnt work any idea? I want to have two for example checkbox1 and checkbox2 there values should be stored in my database colums for example Colum1 colum2.
Thanks in advance for anyhelp

```
<form name="checkbox.php" id="names" action="<?php echo JURI::current(); ?>" method="post">

<p><input type="checkbox" name="game" value="ExampleGame" />b</p>
<p><input type="checkbox" name="Age" value="ExampleAge" />b</p>

<p><input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit Names" /></p>

</form>

<?
if( (isset($_POST['game'])) || (isset($_POST['Age'])) ) {
//first name or last name set, continue-->

$game = $_POST['game'];
$Age= $_POST['Age'];

$db =& JFactory::getDBO();

$query = "INSERT INTO `gameTable` (`game`, `Age`)
VALUES ($game, $age);";
$db->setQuery( $query );
$db->query();

} else {
echo '<h4>One Field Is Required!</h4>';
}

?>
```

Comment: Can you provide the table definition?

Comment: I think your above code will work only if both the checkboxes are checked. Since this won't always be the case you need to change your lines of `$game = $_POST['game'];` to something like `$game = isset($_POST['game'])?$_POST['game']:0;`

Comment: post your table definition

Comment: My table is 3 fields, game_ID Type int Auto_Increment 
game type Varchar
age type varchar

Comment: Found it works whenever I have the Value set to an integer eg, <p><input type="checkbox" name="game" value="11" />b</p>

Comment: When I change that line of code to: <p><input type="checkbox" name="game" value="a" />b</p>

I get this error : 1054Unknown column 'a' in 'field list' SQL=INSERT INTO `inserttest` (`insertColumn`, `columnt`) VALUES (53, a);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$query =  "INSERT INTO `gameTable` (`game`, `Age`) VALUES ('".$game."','".$age."', )";
```

Comment: You need quotes for values variables

Comment: Error :You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 2 SQL=INSERT INTO `gameTable` (`game`, `Age`) VALUES ('ExampleGame','', )

Comment: Just tested it, for some reason it works with numbers just not text? Eg: 
<p><input type="checkbox" name="game" value="11" />b</p>

Comment: When I change that line of code to: <p><input type="checkbox" name="game" value="a" />b</p>

I get this error : 1054Unknown column 'a' in 'field list' SQL=INSERT INTO `inserttest` (`insertColumn`, `columnt`) VALUES (53, a);

Comment: you need quotes `` please add quotes like this  $query =  "INSERT INTO `gameTable` (`game`, `Age`) VALUES ('".$game."','".$age."', )";

Comment: Thanks so much Ayaz Shah, got it to work! Tried to post the answer but Im not allowed :(!

Answer (score 0):

Check the values that come back from your form:

```
 $game = $_POST['game'];
 $Age= $_POST['Age'];
```

You should find that if the checkbox isn't selected, no value (in fact, no field) is returned.
That may be your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use some alerts for troubleshooting:

`echo $_POST['game'];
echo $_POST['Age'];
echo $_POST['query'];`

Even when you don't know what you are doing/doing wrong, try to troubleshoot the problem.
Alerts help alot in PHP to check if you get the values on your variables that you expect.

If you get your query string, test this directly on your database.

Answer (score 0):

I resolve with this easy way:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="field_name" value="N" style="display: none;" checked />
```

On mysql database i have create a trigger

```
 if new.field_name= '' then set new.field_name= 'S';
```